# Ansible 3.6 json token management

Tags: json, loops, ansible

I am trying to write an Ansible playbook to retrieve a list of access tokens for the admin user and to then iteratively delete any tokens associated.

My playbook is as follows:

```
- name: Details
  uri:
    url: "{{api_url}}{{api_token}}"
    method: GET
    headers:
      content-type: "application/json"
      authorization: "Bearer {{ token_fact }}"
    validate_certs: no
    ignore_errors: yes
    status_code: 200
  register: all_tokens
```

The variables used are all setup earlier on other tasks, and this playbook registers the results in the 'all_tokens' variable. When this play is executed the result I received from a debug task that prints the 'all_tokens' variable is as follows:-

```
  all_tokens.json:
    count: 2
    next: null
    previous: null
    results:
    - application: null
      created: '2019-12-02T14:05:47.471743Z'
      description: ''
      expires: '3019-04-04T14:05:47.449065Z'
      id: 314
      modified: '2019-12-02T14:05:47.517372Z'
      refresh_token: null
      related:
        activity_stream: /api/v2/tokens/314/activity_stream/
        user: /api/v2/users/1/
      scope: write
      summary_fields:
        user:
          first_name: ''
          id: 1
          last_name: ''
          username: admin
      token: '************'
      type: o_auth2_access_token
      url: /api/v2/tokens/314/
      user: 1
    - application: null
      created: '2019-12-02T14:08:02.408487Z'
      description: ''
      expires: '3019-04-04T14:08:02.402298Z'
      id: 315
      modified: '2019-12-02T14:08:02.432427Z'
      refresh_token: null
      related:
        activity_stream: /api/v2/tokens/315/activity_stream/
        user: /api/v2/users/1/
      scope: write
      summary_fields:
        user:
          first_name: ''
          id: 1
          last_name: ''
          username: admin
      token: '************'
      type: o_auth2_access_token
      url: /api/v2/tokens/315/
      user: 1
```

How would I iterate through this on the username in the summary_field? e.g. When user is admin do something?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How would I iterate through this on the username in the summary_field? e.g. When the user is admin do something?"*

A: For example *loop* the *results* and test the *item*

```
- debug:
    msg: username is admin
  loop: "{{ all_tokens.json.results }}"
  when: item.summary_fields.user.username == 'admin'
```

gives

```
"msg": "username is admin"
"msg": "username is admin"
```